# Error rendering stateless component: "Can't find variable: React"

Tags: react-native

I have a stateless component in my react-native application defined as follows.

`components/TodoItem.js`:

```
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

const TodoItem = () => (
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <Text>Hello, please remember to do this!</Text>
            <Button
                color="#841584"
                title="Button 1"
            />
            <Button
                color="#241584"
                title="Button 2"
            />
        </View>
);


export default TodoItem;
```

When I use it in the `render()` function of `App.js` like this:

```
import TodoItem from './components/TodoItem';
// . . . other code here
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Hello :)</Text>
            <TodoItem/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React

This error is located at:
    in TodoItem (at App.js:39)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at App.js:37)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:60)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
* components/TodoItem.js:4:8 in TodoItem
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9050:17 in mountIndeterminateComponent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9573:10 in beginWork
- ... 21 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Some help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: You get this message wherever you use React Native components in a file, also within for example test files where you test rendering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add this - `import React from 'react';` although you don't use React on `components/TodoItem.js:`

Comment: Ah. This must be because JSX converts itself to calls like `React.component` . . . ?

Answer (score 1):

Even in a stateless component, we need to import React from `react` package as such:

```
import React from 'react';
```